# how to store scraped item in DB using Item Pipeline for Scrapy?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, pipeline

I want to store scraped items in DB using Item Pipeline

This is my spider

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.python import unicode_to_str
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning
from CollecteurImmobilier.items import CollecteurimmobilierItem

class AnnonceSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "Annonce"
allowed_domains = ["tayara.tn"]
start_urls = ["http://www.tayara.tn/sousse/immobilier-%C3%A0_vendre"]
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\\?o=\\d')),'parse_start_url',follow=True),)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    DivAnnonces = sel.xpath('//div[@class="item"]')
    items = []
    for DivAnnonce in DivAnnonces:
        item = CollecteurimmobilierItem()
        item['link'] = DivAnnonce.xpath('.//h2/a/@href').extract()
        titres = item['link']
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

This is my pipeline

```
from datetime import datetime
from hashlib import md5
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

def __init__(self, dbpool):
    self.dbpool = dbpool

@classmethod
def from_settings(cls, settings):
    dbargs = dict(
        host=settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
        db=settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
        user=settings['MYSQL_USER'],
        passwd=settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True,
    )
    dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
    return cls(dbpool)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    # run db query in the thread pool
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item, spider)
    query.addErrback(self._handle_error, item, spider)
    # at the end return the item in case of success or failure
    query.addBoth(lambda _: item)
    # return the deferred instead the item. This makes the engine to
    # process next item (according to CONCURRENT_ITEMS setting) after this
    # operation (deferred) has finished.
    return query

def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item, spider):

    tx.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM AnnonceGratuit WHERE link = %s
    """, (item['link']))
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        print "Welcome to Python!"
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:

        tx.execute("""
            INSERT INTO AnnonceGratuit (link)
            VALUES (%s)
        """, (item['link'])
        )

        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def _handle_error(self, failure, item, spider):
    """Handle occurred on db interaction."""
    # do nothing, just log
    log.err(failure)
```

This is my mysql.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AnnonceGratuit;
CREATE TABLE AnnonceGratuit (
link VARCHAR,
title VARCHAR
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and in my settings i add this line

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'CollecteurImmobilier.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline': 300,
}
```

But when I run my spider like this

```
scrapy crawl Annonce -o items.xml -t xml
```

there is no errors in my terminal

and I see this message when the spider is running "Item already stored in db"

I success to output the file items.xml 
But nothing is stored in my DB

Please can any one help me 
thinks

Answer (score 0):

try to use db index to detect duplicate

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item, spider):

    try:

        tx.execute("""
            INSERT INTO AnnonceGratuit (link)
            VALUES (%s)
        """, (item['link'])
        )

        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    except:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
```

this should work if you add unique index constraint on link in database